# Spark SQL vs Hive vs Presto SQL for analytics on top of Parquet file

Tags: apache-spark-sql, hiveql, presto

I have terabytes of data stored in Parquet format for analytics use case. There are multiple big tables which needs joins as well and there are heavy queries. The system is expected to be highly scalable. Currently, evaluating Spark SQL, Hive and Presto SQL. Based on theories, all seem to be meeting the requirements. Could you please shed some light on the differences and what should be considered for the above mentioned use case. Tableau will be used for visualization on top of this.

Comment: Presto is scalable but very expensive. Presto is good for small ad-hoc queries. With very big joins and complex queries - Hive on Tez performs better and stable and scalable virtually unlimited. Also Hive will be the cheapest and simple SQL with some additions. Hive requires tuning. Non-equi joins is difficult to implement in Hive.  If you do not need realtime ingestion and integration with side services, Hive is best for batch processing of really big data.Spark is good for processing in smaller chunks, realtime ingestion. Better use all tools for different purposes.IMO

Comment: @leftjoin what makes you say Presto is expansive? I've seen benchmarks showing low TCO when using Presto, also including "supported deployments".

Comment: @user1578872 if you are new to Presto you can meet the community at https://prestosql.io/slack.html. This may help you make the decision that fits your needs best.

Comment: anyway I'd recommend to try Presto along with other tools. Presto is well integrated with Hive. As well as Spark. You can process the same data using Presto, Hive, spark. It is really interesting to know real facts about cost of scaling Presto to be able to process very big data. I have no such possibility to check it, I  know for sure that Presto is reach, capable tool. If you have some cost calculations, please answer